# How to Add Visio title using python win32com in 2016 pro Version?

Tags: python, automation, win32com, visio

**How to Add Visio title using python win32com in 2016 pro Version ?**

1. Can anyone please suggest me how to automate MS Visio title using python win32com?
2. While automating the flowcharts using python , facing one challenge in the end . That is I cant able to modify the flowcharts manually , normally when we create a flowchart manually , we can manually edit . the charts seems to be fixed with fixed connector size . I want to give the users the flexibly to modify it manually also ? Can anyone help me in the same ?